# Do Foreign Keys Impose Uniqueness

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, unique-constraint

Do `FOREIGN KEY`s impose the uniqueness of the the referent?
I.e. if I have a foreign key that refers to a `UNIQUE` constrained column, will the `FOREIGN KEY` column be unique?
I'm particularly wondering about postgresql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, foreign keys are not implicitly unique. And they can't be otherwise it wouldn't be possible to implement a one-to-many relationship, e.g. this:

```
create table customer 
(
   id integer primary key
);
create table orders 
(
   id integer primary key, 
   customer_id integer not null references customer
);

insert into customer values (1);
insert into orders values (1,1), (2,1), (3,1);
```

You *can* however make them unique if you want. This is typically used when modelling a a one-to-one relationship.